# running more than one command line commands inside for loop

Tags: windows, command-line, images

i have a folder containing images and i want to determine its Compression method used. So i would loop through the folder and do a grep Compression like this

and note i have installed grep for windows

```
for %f in (*.jpg) do  identify -verbose "%f" | grep Compression >> info.txt
```

However i need to write the file name and compression technique used so i modified the above command

```
for %f in (*.jpg) do  identify -verbose "%f" | grep Compression & echo "%f" & echo: >> info.txt
```

But the problem is that i get a blank txt file.  Could someone pleas help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection always applies to a single command – `echo: >> info.txt`, in this case – not to the entire command line.

You will need to group commands using `(` `)`'s:

```
for %f in (*.jpg) do (identify -verbose "%~f" | grep Compression & echo "%~f" & echo:) >> info.txt
```

or in a more readable form,

```
for %f in (*.jpg) do (
    identify -verbose "%~f" | grep Compression
    echo "%~f"
    echo:
) >> info.txt
```